# UITableViewCell Delete content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am having trouble with the reusable aspect of my UITableViewCell.  I have different type of data going into the different cells.  When the types of data are the same (example: only images) I have no problem because the new image over writes the old one.  But when the types of data are the same they both are sticking around.

I'm looking for methods or tools for clearing a cell completely.  I have tried many things such as dictionaries to reference the data directly and erase it but that failed because I couldn't consistently tell what data was in what reused cell (especially when scrolling a lot). Others things were

```
 cell.contentView.subviews.removeAll()
```

threw error, another was

```
cell.contentView.removeFromSuperView()
```

but that just made the cell useable and nothing loaded ever.

my code is below, thanks if advance for the help (ignore the date stuff).

```
 if dictionary?["type"]! != nil {


                cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
                cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 1


                cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2, width: 25, height: 25)

                self.tableTextOverLays(i: indexPath.row, type: Int((dictionary?["type"])! as! NSNumber), cell: cell)

                if (indexPath.row == tableFeedCount - 1) && lockoutFeed != true && tableFeedCount == self.allDictionary.count && imageFeedCount == imageDictionary.count {
                    let dictionary = self.allDictionary[indexPath.row]
                    let date = dictionary?["date"] as! Double
                    let date2 = date*100000
                    let date3 = pow(10,16) - date2
                    let date4 = String(format: "%.0f", date3)
                    self.setUpFeed(starting: date4, queryLimit: UInt(11))
                }


            }

            else if (dictionary?["type_"] as! String) == "Image" {
                print("image feed", indexPath.row)



                cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

                cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
                cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 1
                cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2, width: 25, height: 25)
                cell.imageView?.image = imageDictionary[indexPath.row]

                if indexPath.row == tableFeedCount - 1 && lockoutFeed != true && tableFeedCount == self.allDictionary.count && imageFeedCount == imageDictionary.count{
                    let dictionary = self.allDictionary[indexPath.row]
                    let date = dictionary?["date"] as! Double
                    let date2 = date*100000
                    let date3 = pow(10,16) - date2
                    let date4 = String(format: "%.0f", date3)

                    setUpFeed(starting: date4, queryLimit: UInt(11))
                }


            }
            else if (dictionary?["type_"] as! String) == "Video" {
                print("video feed", indexPath.row)



                cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

                cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

                let imagerView = UIImageView()
                imagerView.layer.cornerRadius = 1
                imagerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
                imagerView.image = videoDictionary[indexPath.row]

//                let vidUIView = UIView()
//                vidUIView.tag = indexPath.row

                let asf = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProfileController.playVid2(gestureRecognizer:)))
                asf.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
//                imagerView.addGestureRecognizer(asf)


                let adsf = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProfileController.playVid(gestureRecognizer:)))
                adsf.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
                adsf.require(toFail: asf)                
//              imagerView.addGestureRecognizer(adsf)

                cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(asf)
                cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(adsf)

                cell.contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

                cell.contentView.addSubview(imagerView)

                //cell.contentView.addSubview(vidUIView)


                if indexPath.row == tableFeedCount - 1 && lockoutFeed != true && tableFeedCount == self.allDictionary.count && videoFeedCount == videoDictionary.count{
                    let dictionary = self.allDictionary[indexPath.row]
                    let date = dictionary?["date"] as! Double
                    let date2 = date*100000
                    let date3 = pow(10,16) - date2
                    let date4 = String(format: "%.0f", date3)

                    setUpFeed(starting: date4, queryLimit: UInt(11))
                }

            }
```

Comment: Are you using the delegate pattern in this table view? If not, you may want to check it out. It's pretty slick.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I am using uitableviewdelegate if that is what you are asking, yes.  What I need help with is more advanced than how to use tables.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear if that code is in a view controller or in a UITableViewCell subclass. In any case, you will want to use a UITableViewCell subclass for your cells and do cleanup tasks in `prepareForReuse`:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    imagerView.image = nil
}
```

This will involve removing any data from the cell that you don't want carried over into the cell when it is reused. Clearing images from image views, hiding views that won't be shown for all cell types, etc.

Another solution would be to have multiple cell classes and load the appropriate cell class based on the data type it is responsible for displaying. This will simplify some of the code above and may help to prevent reuse, but it will require a significant refactor by the looks of things.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I expressly say I am not having an issue when the table is full of images and your answer is for tables that all have the same data (an image).  Don't see how that is all helpful given the problem you are solving is not one I am having.  Also in my code the imagerView is created in the scope of said function so referencing it outside of the function would again be pointless.

Comment: @AaronMann Creating the image view in the scope is your problem. I suspect the old image remains in all cases, but when you replace an image view cell with another image view cell, you just stack the image views on top of each other so you don't see that the old one is still there. You'll need to hold a reference to it outside of your scope. It's pretty tough to tell what all is going on with the code you've provided. Typically, you would have a different cell class for each different data type. Each of those cell types would do its cleanup in `prepareForReuse`.